Could a person born in an incorporated US territory before it was incorporated be eligible for the presidency?
Could a person born in an incorporated US territory before it was incorporated be eligible for the presidency? If a person was born in Hawaii before August 21, 1959: would that person be eligible for the US presidency?

Before they became a state, or before they were part of the US?

@JonCuster OK, I have made an edit to make my example more specific.

Hawaii was a US Territory starting in 1898.

1959 is when Alaska and Hawaii became states, not territories.

The general consensus is that, to be a "natural-born citizen", one needs to have been automatically a US citizen at birth (whether it is by birth in the US or by birth abroad to a US citizen parent who qualified to transmit citizenship). So for the purposes of this question, it only matters whether birthright citizenship was granted to a territory; it doesn't matter if it was incorporated. For the purposes of this question, there is no difference between an incorporated territory, and an unincorporated territory to which birthright citizenship has been granted.
Someone born after birthright citizenship has been granted to a territory (whether incorporated or unincorporated) would have automatically been a US citizen at birth, and thus be a natural-born citizen (barring exceptions like children born to a foreign diplomat with diplomatic immunity). Someone born in a territory before birthright citizenship was granted would not have automatically been a US citizen at birth, unless they were born to a US citizen parent who qualified to transmit US citizenship to a child born in that territory. Even if the law later automatically granted US citizenship to the people of that territory born before a certain time, that would still be citizen granted after birth, and therefore, not make the person a "natural-born citizen".
Hawaii was incorporated by the Hawaiian Organic Act of 1900 (as mentioned in the US Supreme Court decision in Hawaii v. Mankichi (1903)), which applied the Constitution and laws of the US to the Hawaii Territory the same as elsewhere in the US. Anyone born in Hawaii after that would have been a natural-born citizen. (The Nationality Act of 1940 and Immigration and Nationality Act of 1952 also included Hawaii as part of the United States for nationality purposes.) Congress also granted US citizenship to people born in Hawaii before 1900, but that would not have made those people natural-born citizens, if they were not already US citizens at birth.
Alaska was incorporated by the Alaska purchase treaty of 1867, according to the US Supreme Court decision in Rassmussen v. United States (1905). Anyone born in Alaska after that (except Native Americans) would have been natural-born citizens. (The Nationality Act of 1940 and Immigration and Nationality Act of 1952 also included Alaska as part of the United States for nationality purposes.) The treaty also granted US citizenship to the inhabitants of Alaska (except Native Americans) in 1867 who did not return to Russia within 3 years, but that would not have made those people natural-born citizens, if they were not already US citizens at birth.
The issue is kind of moot for people born pre-incorporation in incorporated territories, since none of those people are alive today. However, there are lots of people alive today who were born in unincorporated territories before birthright citizenship was widely granted (e.g. Puerto Rico before 1917, the US Virgin Islands before 1927, Guam before 1950, or the Northern Mariana Islands before 1986 or 1978). Those people would not be natural-born citizens unless they were born to a US citizen parent who qualified to transmit US citizenship to a child born in that territory.

correct. It's how the people who became citizens when the US gained independence could run for office.

@jwenting: People who became citizens when the US gained independence were not natural-born citizens. The US constitution required the President to be a natural-born citizen, or a citizen at the time of adoption of the constitution. The first few Presidents were eligible due to the latter condition. My answer is about natural-born citizens. People who became citizens after birth when citizenship was granted to the people of a territory are not natural-born citizens, and cannot be President (assuming they were not alive when the Constitution was adopted).

Can Congress retroactively change the status of a territory, thus granting people born there the status of natural-born citizen retroactively?

@gerrit: I would point you to the following line in Boumediene v. Bush, but I fear that SCOTUS may choose to overturn it in the future: "The Constitution grants Congress and the President the power to acquire, dispose of, and govern territory, not the power to decide when and where its terms apply. To hold that the political branches may switch the Constitution on or off at will would lead to a regime in which they, not this Court, say “what the law is.”"

@gerrit: In my opinion, natural-born citizen status cannot be granted retroactively. In order to be a natural-born citizen, the person would have to have been a US citizen at birth, according to the law in effect at the time of their birth.

@user102008 but retroactively granting citizenship based on birth location would still make the citizenship a right granted by the circumstances of one's birth even if it wasn't effective immediately, so I think a good argument could be made for it counting as "natural-born."  Ultimately it would almost certainly be up to the Supreme Court to decide.

It's worth noting that the constitution's Natural Born Citizen requirement has never been adjudicated by SCOTUS. Had any of the examples given (McCain, Romney, Goldwater) won, you can bet it would have. The next chance will be when Ted Cruz runs again in 2028 (born in Canada to an American mother and a Cuban immigrant to Canada (who eventually took Canadian citizenship)

Re: "a citizen at the time of adoption of the constitution" -- Couldn't it be argued that the people of Hawaii adopted the U.S. Constitution in 1959 and were citizens at that instant in time (same as e.g. George Washington when Virginia adopted it) and so they qualify under this? It doesn't seem definitive that "time of adoption" can only mean "by the original 13 states in 1789".

This is controversial. There's a U Penn law review article that argues that Puerto Ricans are not eligible to be President. But it also points out that Barry Goldwater, who was born in Arizona Territory before it became a state, and John McCain, who was born in the Panama Canal Zone to US citizens when it was a US possession, were both allowed to run for President.
The article argues that Puerto Rico has unique status among US territories that would preclude its citizens from being considered "natural-born citizens" under the Constitution, and this is different from the historical status of Alaska and Hawaii.
If they're correct, I think this means that citizens of Alaska or Hawaii before they became states would be eligible for the Presidency.

the question is are they considered natural-born citizens as per the requirement for the presidency in the constitution

Of course they are. They're not foreigners who were naturalized, they're citizens from birth. Just like Puerto Ricans now.

@NeilMeyer I replaced my answer with a reference to a law review article on the subject.

Part of the argument was that the politicians had U.S. citizenship at birth by paternity and not by location of birth.

I haven't read the entire law review article, so I didn't really get into the guts of why they thought PR is special. But it has something to do with the history of how it was annexed.

@Barmar Reading over the article, their core point is that people born in unincorporated territories (which covers not just PR, but all current US territories) receive citizenship through statute rather than through the constitution, as opposed to people born in incorporated territories, as incorporation (according to their analysis) carries an implicit assumption that the territory is on the inevitable path to statehood. (cont.)

They call out PR as a special case because it's so well-integrated into the US compared to other territories and because it's under commonwealth rule, but their argument is generalized to all unincorporated territories, and the call-out is mostly just to say that PR's special case isn't enough to overcome the distinction they propose: that fundamentally and historically, jus soli only applies in incorporated territories. (Of course, there's been a case going through the courts since 2008 that PR is implicitly incorporated due to various Congressional acts, but that's still not settled.)

George Romney ran for president and he was born in Mexico.  My understanding is that this is an example of "Republican exceptionalism".  A Republican running for president (Romney, Goldwater, McCain) is afforded the broadest possible definition of "natural born citizen", in this case that Romney was a citizen at birth because both his parents were citizens.  A Democrat in the same circumstances would face a much narrower definition of natural born, which was why the place of Obama's birth was actually an issue even when his parentage was not.

@Kirt Romney is mentioned in the law review article, and they said the reason was because he was born to US citizen parents.
